# Why do I get "nan" for Loss when I implement MNIST tensorflow code to my dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

My Project goal is to checkout weight map of neural network for my dataset.

I followed the [MNIST example code](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/not-another-mnist-tutorial-with-tensorflow) and worked fine.

MNIST dataset have 784(28*28) `pixel_data` input and 10 `class_data` output.
My dataset have 72(8*9) `pixel_data` input and 4 `class_data` output.
I made the code to handle my dataset same format as MNIST dataset
but when I train, the Loss is keep giving "NAN" value.

you can check [my code and dataset in my github](https://github.com/wonwooddo/PleaseHelptoApplyMNIST).

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as ran


#데이터를 8x9이미지 형태로 display
def display_digit(num):
    print(y_data[num])
    label = y_data[num].argmax(axis=0)
    image = x_data[num].reshape([8,9])
    plt.title('Example: %d  Label: %d' % (num, label))
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray_r'))
    plt.show()

#데이터를 vector형태로 dispaly
def display_mult_flat(start, stop):
    images = x_data[start].reshape([1,72])
    for i in range(start+1,stop):
        images = np.concatenate((images, x_data[i].reshape([1,72])))
    plt.imshow(images, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray_r'))
    plt.show()

#y_data을 oneshot방법으로 표현 
def oneshot(n):
    if n=="1":
        return [1,0,0,0]
    elif n=="2":
        return [0,1,0,0]
    elif n=="3":
        return [0,0,1,0]
    elif n=="4":
        return [0,0,0,1]

# input, out data 반환, (MNIST에서 사용되는 형태)
def Get_data():
    Glass_dir='./glass_data/'
    csv_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('./glass_data/*.{}'.format('csv'))]

    y_data=[]
    x_data=[]
    for filename in csv_filenames:
        y=oneshot(filename[13])

        csv_file = pd.read_csv(filename)
        df = pd.DataFrame(csv_file).T
        df.columns = df.iloc[0]
        df = df[1:]
        df = df.ffill()
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            y_data.append(y)
        for row in df.iterrows():
            index, data = row
            x_data.append(data.tolist())


    combined = list(zip(x_data, y_data))
    ran.shuffle(combined)
    x_data[:], y_data[:] = zip(*combined)

    y_data=np.array(y_data)
    x_data=np.array(x_data, dtype=np.float32)

    return x_data, y_data

#각 class의 5개씩을 test로 사용
def Get_testdata():
    Glass_dir='./glass_data/'
    csv_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('./glass_data/*.{}'.format('csv'))]

    y_test=[]
    x_test=[]
    for filename in csv_filenames:
        y=oneshot(filename[13])

        csv_file = pd.read_csv(filename)
        df = pd.DataFrame(csv_file).T
        df.columns = df.iloc[0]
        df = df[1:]
        df = df.ffill()
        for i in range(5):
            y_test.append(y)
        df2=df.head()
        for row in df2.iterrows():
            index, data = row
            x_test.append(data.tolist())

    y_test=np.array(y_test)
    x_test=np.array(x_test, dtype=np.float32)
    return x_test, y_test


# In[3]:


x_data, y_data = Get_data()


# In[4]:


x_data


# In[5]:


y_data


# In[6]:


display_digit(ran.randint(0, x_data.shape[0]))


# In[7]:


display_mult_flat(0,200)


# In[8]:


sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 72])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([72,4]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
print(y)


# In[9]:


cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))


# In[10]:


x_train, y_train = Get_data()
x_test, y_test= Get_testdata()
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
TRAIN_STEPS = 2500


# In[11]:


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)


# In[12]:


training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


# In[13]:


for i in range(TRAIN_STEPS+1):
    sess.run(training, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train})
    if i%100 == 0:
        print('Training Step:' + str(i) + '  Accuracy =  ' + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train})) + '  Loss = ' + str(sess.run(cross_entropy, {x: x_train, y_: y_train})))


# In[14]:


for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2, 5, i+1)
    weight = sess.run(W)[:,i]
    plt.title(i)
    plt.imshow(weight.reshape([8,9]), cmap=plt.get_cmap('seismic'))
    frame1 = plt.gca()
    frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)


# In[15]:


plt.show()
```

Comment: As Loss is set to `sess.run(cross_entropy, {x: x_train, y_: y_train})`, I would start by investigating which line of code inside the `cross_entropy` function raises the `nan`. From there you can refine your question. Most of the code you copy/paste here is non-relevant to the question. Narrow down the possibilities and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions: first initialize your weights to something other than zeros. For instance:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[72, 4]))
```

Second, it is recommended that you use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` rather than calculating this yourself. It is more efficient and numerically stable. To do so, get rid of your `softmax` function and change your cost:

```
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b  # your network output before softmax (aka "logits")
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
```